# Is null or negative?

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

I was wondering if there is any place where I can find validation methods similar to this one I've created:

```
public static <T extends Number> Boolean checkNullOrNonPositiveArgument(T object) {
    return Boolean.valueOf(object == null || ((Number)object).doubleValue() <= 0f);
}
```

Guava or Apache Commons... Any clue?

Comment: Your method should be called `checkNullOrNonPositiveArgument` since it will return true for a zero value...

Comment: Too specific. It would be two calls, notNull (checkNotNull), nonPositive (checkArgument(...))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking as a Guava developer, our policy is that if you *really, really* want to have null objects floating around -- which you almost certainly shouldn't -- then you should write your own helper methods.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the guava libraries and Apache commons, you should have a look at [hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial). This is a library for creating matchers for arbitrary types. Matchers are more flexible and powerful than simple check methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Apache Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/package-summary.html#package_description) or the [Hibernate Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/) but I doubt you can find such special validation routines like null or negative as it seems very specific for me.